# How to make a node move where you touch the screen in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have tried many YouTube tutorials but I just can't find one that actually works. I am using Apple's framework `SpriteKit` and I want to make a node move to where I touch. Any help would be appreciated, here some code within my scene:

```swift
let Head = SKNode()

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
      for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            Head.position.x = location.x
      }
}
```

Comment: I think I see the problem, but FYI it would help improve your question if you included some details about what exactly is going wrong when you try to run this code. You say that you want to make the node move to where you touch, but you don't tell us what is happening in the app when you touch on the screen. Presumably, the node is not moving as you expect it to, but it would help clarify the problem if you could give us more details about what exactly is happening and why this is not what you expected.

Comment: The node doesn't move at all

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct except you are using `Head` with a capital H instead of something in camel case like `playerHead`. So this means you are referring to a class definition and not an instance variable. You need to create an instance of the `Head` class within your `GameScene.swift` file and you should be referring to that in your code instead of `Head`.

Here's how I do it in my project. I have a separate Swift file in the project called `Player.swift`:

```
import SpriteKit

class Player: SKSpriteNode {
    let playerTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "playergraphic")
    
    init() {
        super.init(texture: playerTexture, color: .clear, size: playerTexture.size())
    }
    
    // Satisfy the NSCoder required init.
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

So I have established a class called `Player` (you can use a different name but make sure to capitalize it like I have) which is a type of `SKSpriteNode` and I've assigned it a texture which is the image file I created for the player character's graphic. Then I initialize it and also add the required coder init.

Now, turning to the `GameScene` file:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    let player = Player()
    
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        addChild(player)
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches {
            player.position = t.location(in: self)
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for t in touches {
            player.position = t.location(in: self)
        }
    }
    
}
```

First I declare the `player` variable by creating an instance of the `Player` class. I decided to name it `player` but you can name it whatever you want, but you should use camelCase.  Now I can use that reference to `player` elsewhere in this `GameScene` file.

Next, in the `didMove(to:)` method I add the `player` object to the scene so that it will appear on screen as soon as the scene loads. Finally, in the touch methods I reference the `player` object and make changes to it that will be updated in real-time. Here, I'm doing the same thing to change the node's position in two methods just to make the example run a little smoother.

I made this into [a demo project on GitHub](https://github.com/peacetype/SpriteKit-Example-1) which you can download and open in Xcode to see how the file structure is organized.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I have done everything you have said, however I am now getting an error message: Use of unresolved identifier 'Player'

Comment: @Hugh Did you create your `Player` file at the same directory level as your `GameScene` file? Did you declare the `player` variable at the right level within your `GameScene` file (and not inside one of the methods)? It would help if you update your question to show more of your code and maybe a screenshot to show your layout in Xcode. Because the current problem may lie outside the code that you have shown. I updated my answer to include a few more things which I assumed you were doing but may not be.

Comment: @Hugh I updated my GitHub with a link to an example project which demonstrates this and I'm [providing the link here as well](https://github.com/peacetype/SpriteKit-Example-1).